# Pass JSON encoded Array through AJAX as POST

Tags: ajax, json

**What I want**:
I want to pass a *PHP Array* to a *PHP* backend file through *AJAX POST* method.

**What I am doing:**
I am encoding the array with [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) and passing it as a *POST* element with the javascript [encodeURIElement()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function.

**What I get:**
I get a JSON "*array structure*" where each word of my string becomes the key of the array with a NULL value, and this is obviously not working for me.

**What I think:**
I think that the [encodeURIElement()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) is not working fine with the large string, but how else can I send data via *AJAX POST* without character problems?

*Note for downvoters*: I already did RTFM method.

**Some code:**

```
function printJS($action,$position){
global $allPhrases;
/* Tmp function to print the AJAX function which makes a POST, because it is gonna appear lot of times */
return 'onClick="syncronPost(\'/php/backend-checkPh.php\',\'idCont=' . $_POST['idCont'] . '&jsonPh=\'' . $allPhJSON . '\'&act=' . $action . '&pos=' . $position . '\',\'AJXeditArt\'); return false;"';
}
```

Comment: @Siddharth Sorry, I updated my question